# Upload file from One drive into SharePoint Online Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, document-library, .net, onedrive

Need to upload files from one drive to SharePoint Online Site without copying them into Desktop.
How is this possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Using SharePoint Online, you can achieve this very easily. SharePoint online and One Drive provides you **Copy To** functionality in your library.

[image: DOcument Library Copy Functionality]

Using this you can easily copy paste your documents from One Drive to SharePoint site you have permission to.

You can use this link for further reference :  [Copy files and folders between OneDrive and SharePoint sites](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-files-and-folders-between-onedrive-and-sharepoint-sites-67a6323e-7fd4-4254-99a8-35613492a82f)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Ankitkumar said, you can use copy to function to copy files and folders between OneDrive and SharePoint sites.

[image]